# Why does Minecraft starts with a launcher?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Recently I saw something on the internet, something that said that it was possible to open/start up minecraft without launcher. But it is so, why would Mojang still use a launcher to start up Minecraft? I don't have any problems about that; I'm just curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The launcher allows the user to make some customizations to the game before starting play - selecting which profile to play on, for example. It also serves the purpose of authenticating the user to make sure they actually bought the game to begin with. And finally, it provides a platform for the development team to display update notes.

Comment: This explains what the launcher does, but not why it is needed. Everything you mentioned can be handled within the game itself. Plenty of other games do it.

Comment: This is the only possible answer. If you start delving into why the developers chose to present it like this, would be in the realm of asking why are Creepers Green instead of Blue? Developer's personal choice. They can present it in any number of ways.

Comment: And hence is off-topic. Why things are designed the way they are isn't something we can help with. It just to guesses, arguments, and, "but WHY!?"

Comment: Ok, fine, I will ask on Game Development. This organisation sure is big. And I don't have much experience in gaming, so the answer isn't too bad.